# Eloquent one to many Relationship works from one side

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.5

I have two models MediaProfile and MediaProfilesContent. MediaProfile has many MediaProfilesContent and MediaProfilesContent belongs to MediaProfile. My problem is that my relationship works from one side. If i used MediaProfilesContent::all() than i can access data from MediaProfile but if i query from MediaProfile than it gives me this error "Property [cover] does not exist on this collection instance." this means that relationship is not working. Below is my MediaProfile model.

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class MediaProfile extends Model
{    
public function mediaProfilesContent() {
    return $this->hasMany(MediaProfilesContent::class);
 }
}
```

MediaProfilesContent Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class MediaProfilesContent extends Model
{   
public function mediaProfile() {
    return $this->belongsTo(MediaProfile::class);
 }
}
```

Also i add below code in my controller method to test that it returns me data from mediaProfilesContent table or not.

```
$magazines = MediaProfile::where('category', 'Magazines')->get();
dd($magazines[0]->mediaProfilesContent());
return view('magazines', ['magazines' => $magazines]);
```

Above code only gives me data from MediaProfile table not from second table. I need help i am stuck in this error from last week.

Comment: Please add the view code where you try to access `cover`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the relationship data, Use lavarel with(). You can find it in the docs. Refer to the docs for more detail.

An example would be:

$magazines = MediaProfile::with(‘mediaProfilesContent’)->where('category', 'Magazines')->get();

This is an example. You are free to edit as you will. Also keep in mind that if you are not following the convention of eloquent, you might have to make changes to your model. You can set foriegn key, localkey in the model within the ‘return $this->belongsTo(MediaProfile::class);’ like so:

return $this->belongsTo(MediaProfile::class, ‘localkey’, ‘foreignkey,);

Hope this helps :)

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships